# Emission/light shines in one direction but not another

Tags: shaders, transparency, lighting, glass, emission

[image: Glows this way]

[image: Not glowing this way]

How do I make this glow visible regardless of viewing angle angle? The glass transparent settings are visible in my screenshots. Thanks

Comment: If you want to shine through the glass you have to enable the Screen Space Refraction for the material. Its checkbox is visible on the pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly, no difference https://ibb.co/SNn5rD1

Comment: You have to enable it in the render setting too. https://imgur.com/a/roIfia1

Comment: I did enable in render setting. Still no change. :(

Comment: On second though, I flipped normals for the cube, so now the light passes through the  glass regardless of angle viewed